# How to do NULLS LAST in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, null

I'd like to sort my result with all NULL columns last (`NULLS LAST`), as specified in the [SQL:2003 extension T611](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by). Sadly, SQLite seems to not support it. Is there a clever workaround?

Comment: Better late than never: [Native support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246756/5070879) :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

could this work?

```
SELECT ....... ORDER BY COALESCE(col1,col2,col3,etc) IS NULL
```

I am kind of confused by your wording "all NULL columns last". If you want all NULL values last in a particular column, use this:

```
SELECT ....... ORDER BY col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Don't you mean `IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I think it should be `IS NULL` to get the nulls last :)

Comment: Hmm I read the question as "all columns NULL", not sure if that is even what was asked ;-)

Comment: Your second variant works just fine for me since I don't need to sort the non-NULL values.

Comment: In Oracle there is a modification of the ORDER BY clause where you can state you want to sort empty values for a column as first, or as last: `ORDER BY col1 NULLS FIRST`, `ORDER BY col1 NULLS LAST`. See [Oracle DB - ORDER BY clause](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html). Your `ORDER BY col1 is (not) null, col1` is a great substitution for that construct in SQLite.

Answer (score 29):

SQLite 3.30.0+ is supporting `NULLS FIRST/LAST` clauses.

> [Release History (v3.30.0 - 2019-10-04)](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)

> 2. Add support for the NULLS FIRST and NULLS LAST syntax in ORDER BY clauses.

---

> [ORDER BY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby)

> SQLite considers NULL values to be smaller than any other values for sorting purposes. Hence, NULLs naturally appear at the beginning of an ASC order-by and at the end of a DESC order-by. **This can be changed using the "ASC NULLS LAST" or "DESC NULLS FIRST" syntax.**

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY c NULLS LAST;
```

**[db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kiTxgusxzjmAyKZidWZir9/0)**

Answer (score 25):

While I somewhat like Blorgbeard's answer, this variant doesn't care about supplying a valid 'fake' value of the right datatype.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SOMECOL IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, SOMECOL
```

Alternatively, even if you wanted to use a fake value, I would prefer `IFNULL`!

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(SOMECOL,-9999)
```

As Michael noted, SQLite uses `IFNULL`. You can use the ANSI-SQL universal version `COALESCE` as well.

Comment: Minor correction I think ... in SQLite, ISNULL should be IFNULL.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this to fake it:

```
select * from test
order by case ordercol when null then 1 else 0 end, ordercol
```

Comment: why not `order by case when ordercol is null then 0 else 1, ordercol` ? saves a weird bug when someone puts values below -100 in ordercol.

Comment: That's a good point. I just wrote a vague example off the top of my head because we don't know what the data looks like. But your correction works better in general - applied it!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem.
I found out this could work:

(I didn't find any `isnull` function for SQLite)

```
order by ifnull(column_what_you_want_to_sort,'value in case of null')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer in case anyone is looking for the ASC NULLS LAST functionality (especially for TEXT columns) on an SQLite version before 3.30.0 (so it is unavailable).

To place the nulls last, replace them with a value, and then make sure all other values are lower then it:

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN Company IS NULL THEN '2'
    ELSE '1' || Company
END
ASC;
```

Also, for INTEGER columns, if keeping number comparison is needed (as opposed to switching lexicographic with text) then just change the NULL to some text. in SQL comparison TEXT > INTEGER

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN IntegerColumn IS NULL THEN 'null'
    ELSE IntegerColumn
END
ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to reverse the range of my `priority` column and use `order by desc` (sort in descending order). This puts nulls at the end in one go.

Clearly this only works if you control your `priority` ordering column, but it's pretty great if you can swing it!

If that's doesn't work, I found a union query worked. Simply `union` two queries and add the constraint `where not null` on the first and `where null` on the second. The second query will be at the end of the first.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to sort descending with NULL columns first. I am adding records to a List from a while loop after querying, so I simply checked if the column was NULL and used `ArrayList.add(0, Object)` to achieve this.